# rake about database adapter inconsistent with database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

In `database.yml` (rails-generated default file):

```
default: &default
    adapter: sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

When running `rake about`, I have this error:

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.    
Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by    
ActiveRecord).
```

If I add the `pg` gem, then `rake about` gives this output:

```
About your application's environment
Ruby version              2.1.0-p0 (x86_64-darwin13.0)
RubyGems version          2.2.2
Rack version              1.5
Rails version             4.1.0
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Active Record version     4.1.0
Action Pack version       4.1.0
Action View version       4.1.0
Action Mailer version     4.1.0
Active Support version    4.1.0
Middleware                Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #   <ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007f8043154a30>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag
Environment               development
Database adapter          postgresql
Database schema version   0
```

Any idea why this is happening? I want to use the sqlite3 adapter.

Comment: Can you share the complete database.yml contents?

Comment: In database.yml your adapter is still specifying sqlite3, change it to postgresql as below

Comment: I am trying to use sqlite3 as the adapter, not postgres. Rake is saying that I am using the postgres adapter, for some reason.

Comment: @sysofwan Are you on local machine or hosting provider such as Heroku, Nitrous, etc.? If local machine and as you do not want postgresql, remove `gem pg` from Gemfile and run `bundle install`. Let me know the results.

Comment: It's my local machine. I tried your suggestion but rake about is still giving the same error. Thanks!

Comment: @sysofwan Could you please share your `Gemfile` in the question?

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently Rake wan looking for an environment variable DATABASE_URL (which I had set to postgres) and this takes precedence over the database.yml file. Once I deleted the environment variable, everything works fine. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently Rake was looking for an environment variable DATABASE_URL (which I had set to postgres) and this takes precedence over the database.yml file. Once I deleted the environment variable, everything works fine.

Comment: Hey, I am having the same problem. Could you give me a few more details how you solved this problem (if you still remember)?

Answer (score 0):

In `database.yml` change `adapter: sqlite3` to `adapter: postgresql`

You would also need to specify:
`encoding: unicode`
`database: yourapp_development`
`pool: 5`
`username: your_username`
`password: your_password`

If it is a new app that you are playing around with, run the rails new generator again with: `rails new appname -d postgresql`. This will create the app with the postgres adapter.

In your case:

```
default: &default  
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode  
  pool: 5  
  timeout: 5000  

development:  
  <<: *default  
  database: yourapp_development
  username: your_username  
  password: your_password

test:  
  <<: *default  
  database: yourapp_test  
  username: your_username  
  password: your_password  

production:  
  <<: *default  
  database: yourapp_production
  username: your_username  
  password: your_password`
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, but I am trying to use sqlite3 as the adapter, not postgres. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your Gemfile