# Why is my 'pg' gem not being recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I know this question has come up before, but I have taken the advice from previous responses and I keep getting the same error. I don't know why my 'pg' gem is still not working:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
    git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
      repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
      "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
    end
```

CODE:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'bcrypt',  '~> 3.1.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'sprockets'
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: what's the error? what have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: This is the error: Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). I am not sure why it is saying the gem is not loaded. I run bundle install everytime and I have installed pg many times now.

Comment: I'm about to submit an answer, you should edit your question so it includes the error. Always provide relevant info such as the actual errors you've received and steps you've taken if you want to get a helpful answer. There are many things that could be wrong so you should provide others with the context : )

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to use Postgres in your local environment, but your `pg` gem is in your `production` group. Bundler allows you to specify different environment groups for your gems, and you've specified that it should be used only in production. If you run `bundle install` it will still be installed, but it will not be `require`d and used by the application. (You can skip installing the gems in your production group by running `bundle install --without production`)

*If you are indeed trying to use Postgres locally*, which you have not stated but I am inferring, you should move `gem 'pg', '0.20.0'` outside of the `production` group. You should also remove the `sqlite3` gem, the default database adapter for new Rails projects, if you're not planning to use it.

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'bcrypt',  '~> 3.1.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'sprockets'
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# PostgreSQL database
gem 'pg', '0.20.0'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

From this =  gem 'pg', '0.20.0' 
To this = gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'

This should be an easy syntax error.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I changed it to that, but I am getting the same error. I am so confused about why it is saying it is not in my gemfile.

Comment: Try changing it to == gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'

Comment: there is no syntax error

Comment: I am aware of that, just seeing if it is similar to this problem. REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261996/heroku-and-rails-gem-load-error-with-postgres-however-it-is-specified-in-gemfi