# Cannot deploy: Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, pg

I recently got this error. It was working yesterday. I *do* have `pg` gem! The gem is not in a group.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\>git push heroku
Counting objects: 34, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 9.32 KiB | 1.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 34 (delta 28), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.1
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is
only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Resolving dependencies...
remote:        Using rake 12.3.0
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.3
remote:        Using rack 2.0.3
remote:        Using nio4r 2.2.0
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.0
remote:        Using arel 7.1.4
remote:        Using public_suffix 3.0.1
remote:        Using aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using rubyzip 1.2.1
remote:        Using climate_control 0.2.0
remote:        Using unf_ext 0.0.7.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using netrc 0.11.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.0
remote:        Using thor 0.20.0
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using multipart-post 2.0.0
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.18
remote:        Using temple 0.8.0
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.8
remote:        Using sexp_processor 4.10.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Fetching pg 1.0.0
remote:        Using puma 3.11.0
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
remote:        Using i18n 0.9.1
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.4
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.1
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
remote:        Using mail 2.7.0
remote:        Using addressable 2.5.2
remote:        Using city-state 0.0.13
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.7
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Using rack-proxy 0.6.3
remote:        Using unf 0.1.4
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.3
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using faraday 0.13.1
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Using ruby_parser 3.10.1
remote:        Using haml 5.0.4
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.1.0
remote:        Using activesupport 5.0.6
remote:        Using loofah 2.1.1
remote:        Using domain_name 0.5.20170404
remote:        Using stripe 3.9.1
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.0.6
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using html2haml 2.2.0
remote:        Using http-cookie 1.0.3
remote:        Using sass 3.5.5
remote:        Using activejob 5.0.6
remote:        Using activerecord 5.0.6
remote:        Using paperclip 5.1.0
remote:        Using actionview 5.0.6
remote:        Using rest-client 2.0.2
remote:        Using actionpack 5.0.6
remote:        Using cloudinary 1.8.2
remote:        Using actioncable 5.0.6
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.0.6
remote:        Using railties 5.0.6
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using paperclip-cloudinary 1.3.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using responders 2.4.0
remote:        Using haml-rails 1.0.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Using rails 5.0.6
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Using devise 4.4.0
remote:        Using nested_form_fields 0.8.2
remote:        Using rails-reverse-proxy 0.9.1
remote:        Using devise-i18n 1.5.0
remote:        Installing pg 1.0.0 with native extensions
remote:        Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 94 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (9.80s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing pg (0.21.0)
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the
minimum required by ActiveRecord).
remote:        /tmp/build_a9d764dc04e2c3ac37be31055ec0e201/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:176:in `rescue in spec'
... stacktrace ...
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project-staging.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/project-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project-staging.git'
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem with this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034083/148844

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

There's a new version of the pg gem out today (1/10/18) - v 1.0.0.  In your gem file:
`gem 'pg', '0.21.0'`

as suggested by Chloe.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue, reverting back to 0.21.0 for now.

Answer (score 0):

if you are pushing in production try to add pg into the production group like this, and also make sure that sqlite is either in development and test or not present in your gemfile.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**Edit:**

Also make sure your pg version is less then your activerecord version plus if you are on a mac give your pg a version number in the gemfile.